# Scroll function moves exponentially

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scroll function for my canvas which detects distance moved by my mouse and offsets all my images in the canvas.

The problem is i barely move the mouse and the offset number exponentially increases and im not sure why... this is my function that deals with offset calculation:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', scrol_cnv, false);

function scroll_cnv(e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {//right click only
        var x = e.pageX; // get click X
        var y = e.pageY; //get click Y

            function clear() {
                this.removeEventListener('mousemove', updt, false);
            }

            function updt(evt) {
                var difx = evt.pageX - x;
                var dify = evt.pageY - y;

                   //this is where offset is becoming incorrect
                   //offsets is globally defined `window.offsets = {}`
                offsets.cur_offsetx -= difx;
                offsets.cur_offsety -= dify; 

            }
        this.addEventListener('mousemove', updt, false);
        this.addEventListener('mouseup', clear, false);

    }
}
```

Am i subtracting the offset incorrectly ?

Comment: I don't think you want to use `-=`. `cur_offset` should just be the current difference, so just set `cur_offset(x|y) = dif(x|y)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the offset to be based on the offset at the time of `mousedown`.  Events that happen frequently shouldn't be changing things without a basis.

You probably also want to remove your `mouseup` listener, otherwise you get an additional one every click (no functional harm, just unnecessary overhead).

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', scrol_cnv, false);

function scroll_cnv(e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {//right click only
        var x = e.pageX; // get click X
        var y = e.pageY; //get click Y

        // store the initial offsets
        var init_offsetx = offsets.cur_offsetx;
        var init_offsety = offsets.cur_offsety;


            function clear() {
                this.removeEventListener('mousemove', updt, false);
                this.removeEventListener('mouseup', clear, false);
            }

            function updt(evt) {
                var difx = evt.pageX - x;
                var dify = evt.pageY - y;

                //this is where offset is becoming incorrect
                //offsets is globally defined `window.offsets = {}`
                offsets.cur_offsetx = init_offsetx - difx;
                offsets.cur_offsety = init_offsetx - dify; 

            }
        this.addEventListener('mousemove', updt, false);
        this.addEventListener('mouseup', clear, false);

    }
}
```

Comment: I added a note about your event listeners.

Comment: Are you sure i need the mouse up in `clear` given it calls clear?

Comment: Every time `scroll_cnv` is called `this.addEventListener('mouseup', clear, false);` is also called.  It will continually add another listener, and be called multiple times.  You need to either attach the handler once outside of this function, remove the handler at the end, or find another way to have it only happen once.  It's not a big deal, unless the user is dragging a lot of times.  Eventually it'll cause a performance loss.

Comment: But your answer has it attached `updt` function in the remove? Shouldn't it be attached to the clear function

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Copy/Paste mistake.